# python "The else statement used with loops"

Tags: python

This code is from *python tutorial point*
in this chapter *The else statement used with loops* I run the code below but it returns different result:

```
for num in range(10, 20):
    for i in range(2, num):
        j = num / i
        print "%d equals %d * %d" % (num, i, j)
        break
    else:
        print num, "is a prime number"
```

here is the result

```
10 equals 2 * 5
11 equals 2 * 5
12 equals 2 * 6
13 equals 2 * 6
14 equals 2 * 7
15 equals 2 * 7
16 equals 2 * 8
17 equals 2 * 8
18 equals 2 * 9
19 equals 2 * 9
```

But it is not the correct result

```
10 equals 2 * 5
11 is a prime number
12 is equal 2 * 6
13 is a prime number
14 equals 2 * 7
15 equals 3 * 5
16 equals 2 * 8
17 is a prime number
18 equals 2 * 9
19 is a prime number
```

http://ideone.com/2A5Rvx

Comment: I don't see a test for whether the num is a prime number

Comment: And `break` statement would break the inner loop so the inner loop's `else` statement would never be executed.

Comment: You've just copied the code wrong (from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm). It's not the same as the example, so **why would you *expect* the same result?!**

Comment: @jonrsharpe tnx , I found my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **always** break out of the `for` loop. You should only break out of the loop when `num` is divisible by `i`:

```
if num % i == 0:
    break
```

The `else` suit of a `for` loop is only ever executed if no `break` statement was executed. If there is no `i` that can divide `num` then no `break` is ever executed and `num` is a prime number.